# why do we use absolute pressure in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

One of my university doctors asked a question and I couldn't find an answer for so If anyone can help I will appreciate that. The question is why in thermodynamics we usually work with absolute pressure instead of gage pressure where in fluidmechanics we use gage pressure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To describe the phase of matter, something one is interested in when doing thermodynamics, you'd need an absolute measure.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: For example ideal gas law

Comment: @alarge  well im not convinced yet because we still can use the gage pressure by subtracting atmospheric pressure from the absolute.

Comment: @Ali_CHENG Yes, you can convert the numbers back to absolute scale, but why bother with the gauge pressure in the first place when you always need the absolute scale to determine phases. In thermodynamics, phases are what you are usually concerned with. In fluid dynamics, however, things are different: Instead of phase transitions, you mostly care about the movements of a given phase (fluid, gas). what determines this movement is the relative pressure, so the gauge pressure works as well as any other scale.

Answer (score 1):

It all has to do with what you choose as your zero reference point. For the typical ideal gas using absolute pressure ($P = \rho R T$), we can look at the limiting cases:

$$\lim_{T \rightarrow 0} P = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{\rho \rightarrow 0} P = 0$$

which are saying that as the gas cools to absolute zero there is no pressure and as the density approaches zero (meaning there is no gas left in the volume) there is no pressure.

These are just conventions that we apply to a gas based on how we define things from a molecular level. Pressure is a measure of the force per unit air cause by molecules colliding with the surface. If the temperature is 0, the molecules have no translational energy and so there are no collisions. If there are no molecules, then there are no collisions either. In both cases, this is zero pressure.

For solids, conventions may be different. The equation of state for a chunk of metal at room temperature can be defined such that $P = 0$ in that case. So when the solid is under tension, $P<0$ and when it's under compression $P>0$. This convention is chosen based on the notion that $P = 1/3 \text{tr}(\sigma)$ where $\text{tr}(\sigma)$ is the trace of the stress tensor. At reference conditions, there is no stress in the material so there is no pressure.

If you wanted to use a gauge pressure instead of an absolute pressure for a gas, you certainly could but it would be a strange convention. For example, if you took as your reference conditions $\rho = \rho_{0}$, $T = T_{0}$ and $P = P_{0}$ such that $P_0 = \rho_0 R T_0$ then your gauge pressure, $P_g$, EOS would be:

$$ P_g = P - P_0 = \rho R T - \rho_0 R T_0 = R (\rho T - \rho_0 T_0)$$

So you could definitely do it. But why bother, it doesn't really make anything easier or more clear.

As an afterthought, think of the way I've defined pressure above. For fluids, I used a thermodynamic argument for its definition. For solids, I used a mechanical argument. Both are valid for both fluids and solids. In fact, it's not uncommon to use a mechanical pressure when studying fluids -- this is the dynamic pressure given as $\rho u^2$ while the total pressure comes from the thermodynamic argument. For incompressible fluids, the variation in thermodynamic pressures is negligible and it is common to only consider a dynamic pressure, which is essentially a gauge pressure.